# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i keep getting this error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST" and i dont know where i'm wrong.
this is my controller

```
         public function admlogin(Request $request){
             $request->validate([
                'email'=>'required',
                'password'=>'required'
            ]);
             $user = Users::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
             if ($user) {
               if ($request->password, $user->password) {
                   $request->session()->put('id', $user->id);
                   return redirect('index');
                } else {
                   return back()->with('fail','This email is incorrect');
                }
            
             } else {
                 return back()->with('fail','This email is incorrect');
          }
      }
```

and this is my web.php

```
     Route::post('/adlogin', [UserController::class,'admlogin'])->name('adlogin');

     Route::get('index/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```

and my login.blade.php

```
         <form action="adlogin" method="POST">
          @csrf
         <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Try clearing your route cache once and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You cant define route simply as

```
<form action="adlogin" method="POST">
```

have to use laravel helper to define route or url, as

```
 <form action="{{ route('adlogin') }}" method="POST">
```

or

```
<form action="{{ url('adlogin') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i did this yet i'm still having same error

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('admlogin/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply